# asp.net membership - shows up as admin even though not in web tool

Tags: asp.net, membership

when i run this code, i get back true

```
bool isAdmin =  Roles.IsUserInRole(item.loginName, "Administrator");
```

but when i bring up the Security tab in the Asp.net Website administration tool, this user doesn't exist (or atleast i dont see this user in the list)

when i go to the database, i do see this users in the **aspnet_Users** and **aspnet_UsersInRoles** table but i dont see this users in the **aspnet_Membership** table.

do you know how this is possible.  is there any other way i can clear out this user since i can't delete them using the asp.net tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the user from aspnet_Users then aspnet_UsersInRoles